# How to enable the Filter toolbar in Hedgehog Razl

Tags: razl

What do I need to do in order to enable the filters toolbar button in Razl?

[image: Razl Toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

To filter a particular field, you need to go to a Field Information Pane (left or right, it doesn't matter) and right-click on a field then select <kbd>Ignore Field 
 'FieldName'</kbd>.

[image: Hhogdev Razl Field Filtering]